# Batch check for empty user input

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, if-statement

I am struggling with a simple check if the user input was just empty (Enter) and in case set the variable to a new value... spend an hour but it does not work.
Goal is to have the entered Value beginning with a backslash OR just an empty string if nothing was entered.

Code:

```
SET myTargetServerInstanceName=anyNOPEdummyValue
SET /P myTargetServerInstanceName=Enter Target Server INSTANCE Name:    
IF %myTargetServerInstanceName%==anyNOPEdummyValue SET myTargetServerInstanceName=
IF NOT %myTargetServerInstanceName% == [] SET myTargetServerInstanceName=\%myTargetServerInstanceName%
```

this results in error:

> SET was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The usual way to check for an empty variable is compare if its `"%value%"` is `""`. However, in order for this to work you *must* delete the variable before the `set /P`, because if the user just press enter the previous value of the variabe is *not* modified:

```
set "var="
set /P var=
if "%var%" equ "" set "var=default value"
```

However, a simpler method is use `if defined`:

```
set "var="
set /P var=
if not defined var set "var=default value"
```

Previous method would not require delayed expansion.

As a corollary of previous description, you may get the same result this way:

```
set "var=default value"
set /P var=
```

Comment: This indicated to the right direction. The following is working for me: 
IF [%myTargetServerInstanceName%] == [] SET myTargetServerInstanceName = \%myTargetServerInstanceName%

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the `set /p` operation was sucessful

```dos
set /p "var=prompt text?" || set "var=default value"
```

If you prefer the `set / if`, when you check for a value that can be empty or contain spaces, it is better to use quotes

```dos
if "%var%"=="" set "var=default value"
```

or, as a variable without content is not defined, you can check this case with

```dos
if not defined var set "var=default value"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to enclose *both* sides of the `if` comparison parts in `"`:

```
SET myTargetServerInstanceName=anyNOPEdummyValue
SET /P myTargetServerInstanceName=Enter Target Server INSTANCE Name:    
IF "%myTargetServerInstanceName%"=="anyNOPEdummyValue" SET myTargetServerInstanceName=
IF NOT "%myTargetServerInstanceName%"=="" SET myTargetServerInstanceName=\%myTargetServerInstanceName%
```

If one of the comparison expressions (left or right of the `==`) expands to an empty string, you will receive a syntax error.